# Can a graduate student (in Canada) submit his tax file corresponding to the last year?

Tags: taxes, canada, international, student

I'm an international graduate student living in Canada from September 2016. I didn't submit any tax forms corresponding to 2016 last year. Now, I am about to gather all required slips (T4, T4A, T2202A, etc.) of 2017. I'm wondering whether or not I can submit the forms of 2016 and 2017 simultaneously.

Answer (score 1):

I just found a FAQ-based clarification [here](https://www.uwo.ca/international/iesc/current/Money%20and%20Taxes/income_tax/tax_faq.html) saying:

> I didn't file my income taxes in previous years. Can I file taxes for
>   past years now?
>
> Yes. You can file a tax return to claim a refund for the **previous ten
>   years**. Attach receipts for all the deductions or credits you are
>   claiming. Tax forms for previous years can be downloaded from the
>   Canada Revenue Agency website.